# rect/offsetTop/offset().top/any sort of position returning 0 for all elements in container

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

When getting the height/position of the container it displays correctly, but when getting the top position (or any position) of any containing elements it returns 0. Also when using `.getBoundingClientRect()` it returns 0 for all values (top, left, right, bottom, height, width). When I hover over them in inspector they are showing the correct width/height.

They are all `display: block;`-- any ideas as to what could be happening?'

Comment: We can't help you without seeing your code. My instinctive guess is that the top of all these elements you refer to really is 0.

Comment: It's sounds like you running the code before the elements are loaded. make sure your script is at the bottom of the page, have a `defer` attribute, or running inside `DOMContentLoaded` event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was returning 0 as it was in a component that had width/height of 0 for all values on page render. Once I set the component to only render given specific props, the problem went away.